# Python tool to get an outline map of counties/states given the bounding coordinates?

Tags: gis, geopandas, shapefile

I am looking for a python tool that gives me the county and/or state boundaries in an image format if I provide the 4 corners in lat/lon coordinates. I plan to overlay some satellite images on these.

I briefly dabbled with geopandas and I could get a map of North America, but having something more zoomed in would be better.

Thanks.

Comment: `geopy` geocoding tool is what you looking for.

Comment: Try cartopy. Geopandas would also work fine. Show us what you tried and we can help.